# How to print specific data on Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

[image: screenshoot 1]
[image: screenshoot 2]

Screenshoot 1 contain all of my data on database table while screenshoot 2 is detail of someone data whenever i click on search icon on screenshoot 1.
What i need is, how to print only someone data without pass the ID/parameter on my url for calling the controller? Btw, im using DOMPDF as my pdf generator.

Here my code : 
**Model**

```
public function view_kartu($kode_pasien)
{
   $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tb_pasien where kode_pasien='$kode_pasien' LIMIT 1");
   return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Controller**

```
public function cetakkartu($id) {  
 //set a value for $kode_pasien
$kode_pasien = $id;  
// Load all views as normal
$data['title'] = "Data Pasien | Praktik Dokter Umum";
$data['kartu_pasien'] = $this->a_model->view_kartu($kode_pasien);
$this->load->view('cetak-kartu', $data);
// Get output html
$html = $this->output->get_output();

// Load library
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');

// Convert to PDF
$this->dompdf->load_html($html);
$this->dompdf->render();
$this->dompdf->stream("cetak-kartu" . ".pdf", array ('Attachment' => 0));}
```

**View for all data in my database table (screenshoot 1)**

```
    <div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
                <div class="btn-group">

                    <a href="<?=base_url();?>index.php/a_controller/regismanual"/>
                    <button  class="btn-success btn">
                    Tambah  Pasien</button>
                    </a>

                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table id="rekam" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Kode Pasien</th>
                    <th>Nama Pasien</th>        
                    <th>Email Pasien</th>
                    <th>Alamat Pasien</th>
                    <th>Tanggal Lahir</th>
                    <th>Umur</th>
                    <th>JK</th>
                    <th>No. Telp</th>
                    <th>Opsi</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                if(isset($pasien)){
                    $no=0; foreach ($pasien as $isi): $no++;
                        # code...

                ?>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->kode_pasien?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->nama_pasien?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->email_pasien?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->alamat_pasien?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->tanggal_lahir?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->umur?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->kode_jk?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->no_telp?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/a_controller/updatepasien/<?php echo $isi->kode_pasien?>">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-success btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/a_controller/deletepasien/<?php echo $isi->kode_pasien?>" onclick="return confirm('Apakah anda yakin akan menghapus data ini?')">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-inverse btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
                        </a>
                        <a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/a_controller/detail/<?php echo $isi->kode_pasien?>">
                        <button type="button" class="btn-warning btn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php endforeach;}?>

                </table>

                </div>
```

**View for my detail data (screenshoot 2)**

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
                <div class="btn-group">

                    <a href="<?php echo base_url("index.php/a_controller/cetakkartu/4");?>"/>
                    <button class="btn-success btn">
                    Cetak Kartu Berobat</button>
                    </a>

                </div>
                <br>
                <br>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">



                    <?php
                    if(isset($kartu)){
                        $no=0; foreach ($kartu as $isi): $no++;
                            # code...

                    ?>  

                    <tr>
                    <td>Kode Pasien</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->kode_pasien?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Nama Pasien</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->nama_pasien?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Email Pasien</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->email_pasien?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Alamat Pasien</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->alamat_pasien?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Tanggal Lahir</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->tanggal_lahir?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Umur</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->umur?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>Jenis Kelamin</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->kode_jk?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>No. Telp</td>
                    <td><?php echo $isi->no_telp?></td>
                    </tr>

                <?php endforeach;}?>

                </table>

                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Like you see, i need to pass someone ID like this

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("index.php/a_controller/cetakkartu/4");?>"/>
                <button class="btn-success btn">
                Cetak Kartu Berobat</button>
                </a>
```

It will only print someone with ID = 4 , it makes me cant print others person detail data. Did i need to change the ID whenever i want to print someone data? It's really hard.
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url("index.php/a_controller/cetakkartu").$kartu[0]['kode_pasien'];?>"/>
    <button class="btn-success btn">
        Cetak Kartu Berobat
    </button>
</a>
```

Comment: Try to provide some brief about your answer

Comment: print the specific patient detail on button click  and give the url dynamically with patient_id